# Is there a nice open set proof that multiplication is continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

For students in a first course in analysis or topology, proving that certain function are continuous can be very tricky.  However, some proofs which are difficult for students to prove using the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of continuity are much easier to prove using the topological definition that the pre-image of every open set be open.  For example, it is much easier for students to prove that $f(x)=x^2$ is continuous using open sets rather than $\epsilon-\delta$. One particularly challenging proof is showing that multiplication $\cdot \colon \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous.  Is anyone aware of a slick way to prove multiplication is continuous using open sets?  Any attempt I make seems to  more or less be just as complex as the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition.

Comment: Well, how do you define the open sets in $\Bbb R$, or $\Bbb R \times \Bbb R$?

Comment: $U$ is open $X$if for every $x\in U$ there is a ball entirely contained in $U$

Comment: Sure, but how do you define "ball"? With an $\varepsilon$. My point is that at some point you need to use the actual topology of $\Bbb R$, defined in terms of $\varepsilon$-balls.

Answer (score 17):

Not sure if you would be interested in this approach, but it is easy to prove with the sequence definition of continuity. Suppose $x_n \to x$ and $y_n \to y$, then
$$
x_ny_n = (x + (x_n-x))(y + (y_n-y))  = xy + x(y_n-y) + y(x_n-x) + (x_n-x)(y_n-y)
$$
so that by triangle inequality
$$
|x_ny_n - xy| \leq |x| |y_n-y| + |y||x_n-x| + |x_n-x||y_n-y|
$$
since $x_n \to x, y_n \to y$ all three terms on the right tend to zero.

Comment: Ah, that is pretty nice.  I'll tuck that away for safe keeping... thanks!

Comment: That's really neat.

Comment: Works for addition too.

Comment: And inversion of non-zero elements and complex numbers.

Comment: @TomCollinge Can you explain how you proved continuity of inversion of complex numbers with this method?

Comment: Nevermind, solved. For those wondering, let $x_n\rightarrow x$. We need to prove $x_n^{-1}\rightarrow x^{-1}$. $x_n^{-1}x_n=(x^{-1}+(x_n^{-1}-x^{-1}))(x+(x_n-x))=1$. Expand and get $0=\lVert x^{-1}(x_n-x)+x(x_n^{-1}-x^{-1})+(x_n^{-1}-x^{-1})(x_n-x)\rVert$. Again use the triangle inequality; in the limit, only the second term survives and you get the desired result.

Comment: Proving continuity of addition of vectors in a general normed space (and continuity of multiplication by scalars) is similar to this method.

Answer (score 3):

Or you could (i) show (e,g by picture) that topologically speaking open balls are equivalent to open squares,
 (ii) then use the fact that $f(x,y)= xy $ is monotone in each variable $x,y>0$  and
 (iii) use  the  multiplicative properties of $f$  to show e,g that if $.9 x_0<x<1.1 x_0$ (and likewise for $y$), 
then $ .9^2  f(x_0, y_0) <f(x,y)< 1.1^2 f(x_0, y_0)$
In other words, make use of the multiplicative structure of the reals as much as possible. This proves continuity in the open first quadrant.

Answer (score 1):

As nullUser said, if we take $x_n\to x$ and $y_n\to y$, we need to show that $x_n y_n \to xy$. However, the triangle inequality part can be a little bit simpler. Notice that $|x_n y_n - xy| = |x_n y_n - xy_n + xy_n - xy|$
$\leq |x_n y_n - xy_n| + |xy_n - xy| = |y_n||x_n-x| + |x||y_n-y|$.

Now, the right hand side goes to zero per assumption, meaning the product also converges.

Comment: Very nice, thanks!

Comment: This is a circular argument -- you're trying to prove that multiplication is continuous, but at the end there you used the fact that multiplication is continuous to show that the right hand side goes to zero.

Comment: Doesn't NullUser also use circular reasoning then? In saying |x_n - x| |y_n - y| approaches zero?